# An Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé game

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\sigma = \{E \}$ be a signature with a binary relation symbol $E$. The $\sigma-$ structures $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are given as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> $(i)$ Show that the duplicator wins the game $\mathfrak{G}_2(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B})$.
>
> $(ii)$ Give a formula $\varphi \in FO[\sigma]$ with minimal [quantifier rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_rank), such that $\mathcal{A} \models \varphi$ and $\mathcal{B} \not\models \varphi$.

For $(i)$, I don't see how the duplicator can win in round two. For example, if the spoiler picks the vertex $c$, then the duplicator has to pick a vertex in $\mathcal{A}$ which also has two outgoing edges, but no such vertex exists. What am I missing here?

$(ii) \forall x \forall y \forall z (E(x, y) \land y \neq z \land x \neq y \rightarrow \lnot E(x, z))$

Here I'm saying that every vertex has at most one outgoing edge.

What do you think of my answers?

Comment: Your answer to part (ii) looks fine, but the conjunct $x\ne y$ is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: $(i)$, you write:

> if the spoiler picks the vertex $c$, then the duplicator has to pick a vertex in $\mathcal{A}$ which also has two outgoing edges.

But that's not true. Remember that Duplicator wins if, at the end of the game, the **atomic types** of the tuples built are the same. For example, if Spoiler picks $c$, Duplicator picks $4$, Spoiler picks $a$, and Duplicator picks $3$, Duplicator will win the play. We don't check at the end of a play of the Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game that the tuples built have matching out- (or in-)degrees.

In fact, there is very little Spoiler can do in two moves.